# Custom TTF fonts in QGIS input app on iPhone

Tags: font, mergin-maps, ttf

Is it possible to use custom TTF fonts in QGIS input app on iPhone, or do I have to convert every single character to SVG instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom (TTF) fonts are not yet supported by InputApp, and the progress on this issue is tracked in the ticket https://github.com/lutraconsulting/input/issues/1195

(disclaimer: I am part of the InputApp development team)

Comment: Thx @Peter, that's good news. As a temporary workaround I convert my TTF to SVG glyphs online and use Expression String Builder to build an inline SVG data URI to display the symbols.

Comment: Unfortunately, the inline SVGs mostly produce questionmarks when they are displayed the first time. Guess QGIS has some timing issues here. When I convert the glyphs to SVG symbols and store them in the file system, everything is fine.